# Running a LinkSys WRT400N router with 3rd party firmware

Tags: router, dd-wrt, firmware, tomato

Does anyone have any experience with the LinkSys WRT400N router and installing 3rd party firmware on it?  Is there a more stable choice between DD-WRT and Tomato?  Any benefits one way or the other?  Any reason I shouldn't use either, or a suggestion for a different firmware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have mainly used DD-WRT and I have to say it is a very good firmware, it allows you to use many advanced (hidden) features within your router.

I would recommend installing it as I would consider it to be better than the stock linksys firmware.

Installation of DD-WRT is very straight forward and DD-WRT provide a lot of documentation to aid this.

The first step is to go to the [router database](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) and enter in your model "WRT400N" a listing for your router will come up and you will be able to download all necessary files.

You can also look at further documentation about your router from the [DD-WRT Wiki](http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_WRT400N)

As of writing the latest version of DD-WRT is build 14896, don't use the version found from the wiki.

Update July 2014: [Check here](http://dd-wrt.com/site/support/other-downloads?path=others%2Feko%2FBrainSlayer-V24-preSP2%2F) for the latest WRT400N build.